# JqGrid with subgrid and local data not working in IE9 - throws - "SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation"

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

I am new to JQGRID and I am using version 4.7.1.

I am trying to create JQGRID with SUBGRID. The code is working as expected in Google chrome, but I am getting the below mentioned error in IE9.

```
SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation. 
jquery.jqGrid.src.js, line 1639 character 6
```

How can I resolve the error and make it work in IE9. Kindly do the needful.Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-    ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />




<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 




<style>
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td 
{ 
border-right-color: transparent;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;    
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
position:relative;
vertical-align:text-top;
white-space:normal !important; 
}

th.ui-th-column { border-right-color: transparent !important }

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable
{
table-layout:auto;
}

.top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }

.cursorPointer:hover{
cursor:pointer
}


.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;    
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
position:relative;
vertical-align:text-top;
white-space:normal !important;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div >
<table id="grid"></table>
</div>


</body>


<script type="text/javascript">

var mydata = [
{id: "1", label:"No 1", number:"02200220", status:"OPEN", level:"0", parent:  "", isLeaf: false, expanded:false, loaded:true},
{id: "2", label:"No 2", number:"77733337", status:"ENTERED", level:"0", parent: "", isLeaf: false, expanded:false, loaded:true},
{id: "6", label:"No 2a", number:"12345123", status:"WIRED", level:"1", parent: "2", isLeaf: false, expanded:false, loaded:true},
{id: "7", label:"No 2a1", number:"1111111111", status:"WIRED", level:"2", parent: "6", isLeaf: true, expanded:false, loaded:true},
{id: "3", label:"No 3", number:"02200111", status:"OPEN", level:"0", parent: "", isLeaf: false},
{id: "4", label:"No 3a", number:"02200221", status:"OPEN", level:"1", parent: "3", isLeaf: true, expanded:false, loaded:true},
{id: "5", label:"No 3b", number:"02242320", status:"CLOSED", level:"1",   parent: "3", isLeaf: true, expanded:false, loaded:true}
];

var grid = $("#grid");


grid.jqGrid({
// data: mydata, // doesn't work
datatype: "local",
colNames: ['Id', 'Label', 'Number', 'Status'],
colModel: [
{ name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sortable:false},
{ name: 'label', index: 'label', width: 180, sortable:false},
{ name: 'number', index: 'number', width: 120, formatter: function    (cellValue, option, rowObject) 
{
        return "<span><img src='images/play.png'></img></span><span style='padding-left:10px'><img src='images/Download-icon.png'><span>";
    } },
{ name: 'status', index: 'status', width: 120, sortable:false } ],
hidegrid: false,
gridview: true,
sortname: 'id',    
loadonce: true,

treedatatype: 'local',
ExpandColumn: 'label',
height: 'auto',
pager : "#gridPager",
caption: "Prouct Page Table"
});


// we have to use addJSONData to load the data
grid[0].addJSONData({
total: 1,
page: 1,
records: mydata.length,
rows: mydata
});



</script>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeGrid don't works with `datatype: "local"`, but one can use `datatype: "jsonstring"` instead. One need just use `datastr: mydata` instead of `data: mydata`. You should use `parent: "null"` instead of `parent: ""` additionally for top level icons. It allows to have local sorting additionally. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) for the corresponding code example.

The reason of the problem "jquery.jqGrid.src.js, line 1639" could be the bug with the usage of `firstElementChild`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220611/315935) for details. You can download code of `jquery.jqGrid.src` of jqGrid 4.7.0 after the fix from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.7.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-firstElementChild.js). Alternatively you can download beta version of new free jqGrid from [my fork of jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).